# Proxmox reduce (shrink) the hard disk VM

Tags: virtual-machine, proxmox

Accidentally added a 300GB virtual machine to the proxmox node, how now to remove this space? is it possible to use the command

```
qemu-img resize /media/storage2/images/101/vm-101-disk-0.raw -299G
```

so as not to lose all the data??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk12N.png)

Comment: I don't know, but it's a good question.